# Locate element by xpath or css selector

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
  <button type="button">Select</button>
  <button type="button">Cancel</button>
 </div>
```

I want to `click` the **Select** `button` as one of my automation step, But i have only the class and the button inside. How can i use `cssSelector` or `xpath` or `className` and get the **Select** value?

Comment: Could you provide correct formatted HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming Select button is inside `<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">`, try with below `XPath` :-

```
//div[@class = 'ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[text() = 'Select']
```

You can use `cssSelector` also here but you can find it using index instead of `text` because there is no way in `cssSelector` to locate an element by `text`, so you can use as like below :-

```
 div.ui-dialog-buttonset > button:nth-child(1)
```

Comment: @ Gaur: Thanks its working. Could be explain why we have used the '/' in between. Can we use cssSelector ? If so please provide the syntax

Comment: @Pradeeba Yes you can use `cssSelector` as well but using index not using their text... see updated answer..

Comment: @Pradeeba In XPath `/` means Selects from the root node and
`//` means Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are...

Comment: @Pradeeba Using XPath you can also use `//button[text() = 'Select']` if in your page has only single button with text Select..

Comment: To know more about `XPath` syntax follow this link..http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement selectButton = findElement(By.xpath("//button[text() = 'Select']"));
selectButton.click();
```

Comment: Also, take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp